# Zapier: Code not returning all values expected

Tags: python, regex, zapier

I am working with Code by Zapier and having trouble telling if my regex is wrong or some other part is wrong ( I think the latter)

I am pulling a URL, this URL has several 9 digit IDs that get appended to the end of the URL. I was told to try and extract these IDs and rebuild the URLs so we can post API calls for each of them.

I am a Python newb but so far I have this but it only returns the first 9 digit ID, I am hoping for an array so I can rebuild the URLS with each specific ID. This is my code so far:

```
import re
    urls = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', input_data['input'])
         return [
             {'url': url} for url in urls
]
```

The input _data would be `"https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/123456789,098765432.json"`

As I said, it just returns the first ID. I know I don't have the code to rebuild the URLs or anything just trying to take it one step at a time!

IS my regex incorrect or the way I am returning them? Thanks!

Comment: I get a 400 if I follow the link.

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. I've got good news and bad news.

Good news is, your regex works! So no sweat there. Downside, you're running into a weird corner case with code steps. It's not documented because we don't encourage its use (it's confusing, as you can tell). When you return an array from a code step, it functions like a trigger. That is, subsequent steps run for each item in the array (but the UI only shows the first).

If that's the desired behavior, you can safely ignore the weird test and complete the zap. If you don't want to fan out, you should instead parse out the comma separated string and act on it later.

If you need more direction, let me know a bit about what your other actions are and I can advise from there.

Side note, the reason you're seeing the error message with Willem's function above is that your python code must either set the `output` variable to a value or return an object. Either of `return get_digits(input_data['input'])` or `output = get_digits(input_data['input'])` should work.

Comment: Hi David,

Sorry I missed this comment! Thanks for getting back to me!

So, if I use an Action step after this that is a Python code step to make a POST call based off each of the URLs returned in my array you are saying it will actually run through the array in my Python code section? I can give this a go today and let you know how I get on.

Thanks!

Comment: That's correct! If step A returns 5 urls and step B does a post request to that url, when it's run for real, step B will run 5 times for every time A triggers. Be careful, as this can potentially running through your task allotment quickly!

Answer (score 0):

The code works correct on my machine:

```
import re

def get_digits(s):
    return [{'url':url} for url in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b',s)]
```

If I then call this with the sample input, I get:

```
>>> get_digits("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/123456789,098765432.json")
[{'url': '123456789'}, {'url': '098765432'}]
```

So a list with two *dictionaries*. Each dictionary contains one key, a `'url'` that is associated with the string that contains *one or more digits*.

In case you want to match only nine-digit sequences, you can make the regex more restrictive (but this can only *decrease* the number of matches):

```
import re

def get_digits(s):
    return [{'url':url} for url in re.findall(r'\b\d{9}\b',s)]
```

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for tightening up the regex!

The thing is when using Code by Zapier section of Zapier , it gets really particular about things and keeps telling me to 'Please define output or return early"

It so frustrating to code in Zapier but I have no choice in this scenario unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Argh so frustrating, I decided to try JavaScript and multiple methods don't output anything

```
<script>
var str = "https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/382411278,374879346,374879343.json";
var tickets = str.match(/\d{9}/g);
for(var i = 0; i<tickets.length; i++)
    {
document.write("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/"+tickets[i]+".json</br>")
}
```

or

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/382411278,374879346,374879343.json";
    var tickets = str.match(/\d{9}/g);

    for(var i = 0; i<tickets.length; i++)
    {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +="https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/" +tickets[i] + "<br />"
    }

}
</script>
```